# Probability distribution and likelihood are same?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

I'm confused by a question I need to solve. I'm given the probability function

$$P(Y=y,\theta)=f(y,\theta)=\frac{(\theta t)^y}{y!}e^{-\theta t}, y = 0,1,2,\dots;\theta>0$$

Is it true that $P$ is also the likelihood function?

If also given 20 separate intervals for $Y$, is it true that the maximum likelihood is given by $\frac{\partial P}{\partial\theta}=0$? Since the solution is $\theta_{max}=\frac{y}t$, where $t$ is time, and each interval is given as one hour, then is it correct that $\theta_{max}=y_{\max}$ from the data set?

Just wanted to make sure I'm getting this right. Would appreciate some feedback.

Comment: What do you mean by "20 separate intervals of $Y$?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting you correctly you are given $20$ independent samples that are Poisson-distributed with mean $\theta t$ (where $t$ is the same for each one - representing the duration of some interval of time disjoint from all the others during which you measure the number of clicks of a Poisson process) and you're trying to get the MLE for $\theta.$ The joint distribution for $n=20$ samples is just the product cause they're independent $$ P(Y_1=y_1,\ldots, Y_n=y_n;\theta) = \frac{1}{\prod_i y_i!}(\theta t)^{\sum_i y_i}e^{-n\theta t}.$$ This thing, when viewed as a function of $\theta,$ is the likelihood function.

To get the MLE you maximize this. When you do so by taking the derivative and setting equal to zero, you will get $\theta_{MLE} = \frac{1}{nt} \sum_i y_i.$

I can't follow how you got $\theta_{MLE} = y_{max}$ (also, what is $y_{max}$? The largest $y$?) but it's incorrect.

Comment: I'm actually given 20 separate one-hour intervals (that is for $t$). In each interval, there is a certain number of incoming calls recorded. So, in my understanding, the likelihood function in this case is just $P$?

Comment: @sequence It's the joint distribution for your data $y_1\ldots y_{20}.$ How would you plug all $20$ of those numbers into $P$? (And as to the first sentence, that is exactly what I was assuming.)

Comment: If I differentiate  your likelihood function w.r.t. $\theta$ I get $\theta = \frac{9}{t}$. But what is $t$ then, it is $t=20$?

Comment: @sequence $t$ is the duration of the time intervals (which you said was one hour). So I guess if you used my method and got $9/t$ the sum of the $y_i$ was 180? Your estimated rate is $\theta = 9/t$ which is $9$ calls per hour. When you think about it, this should make sense. You observed $180$ calls in $20$ hours.